# Hover effect on image and button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image with a button centered in the middle of my image. I want when I hover on my image to add an opacity on my image and change the color of my button. The problem I have is that, when I hover over my image, my button also has an opacity which I don't want. I have tried z-index, but it is not working.

This is what i have done so far:

```css
#asides .aside-map {
  min-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
}

#asides .aside-map .btn-main.map {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

#asides .aside-map:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#asides .aside-map:hover > .btn-main.map {
  background-color: rgb(254, 204, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(254, 204, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="asides">
  <a class="aside-map">
    <div class="btn btn-main map">
         <span class="fa fa-map-marker">Show Map</span> 
     </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

I am not able to display an image in the snippet, but this is how it looks like:

[image]

And when I am hovering on my image this is what i have:

[image]

Both my image and button have an opacity of 0.5 and I would like to have my button without any opacity

Comment: Set your background to a pseudo element and set the opacity on that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `opacity: 0.5` set opacity for the whole element.

You can use `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` instead:

```css
#asides .aside-map {
        min-height: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: .3s ease-in-out;
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
    }

        #asides .aside-map .btn-main.map {
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
        }

        #asides .aside-map:hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

            #asides .aside-map:hover > .btn-main.map {
                background-color: rgb(254, 204, 0);
                border: 2px solid rgb(254, 204, 0);
                opacity: 1;
            }
```

```html
<div id="asides">
  <a class="aside-map">
    <div class="btn btn-main map">
         <span class="fa fa-map-marker">Show Map</span> 
     </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: When i am using background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), the image is not displayed, only the background color!